# RegEx to split names into FirstName, MiddleName, FamilyName

Tags: regex

I need a regex to split a name into first name, family name (surname) and everything in between as (possibly empty) middle names. Several items on stack overflow handle this, but they don't handle the following names, with common European layouts:

```
Gloria VanderBilt
Gloria van der Bilt
Gloria v.d. Bilt
G. v.d. Bilt
```

Us humanoids have no problem recognizing the first name, the middle names and the family name. However a regular expression for this is not so simple.

After trying, I've got the following RegEx:

```
^\b(\w+)\b(.*)\b(\w+)\b
```

Select three items:

- A word in the beginning,
- then as much characters as possible,
- finally a word at the end.

The first three names are correct, I even get"Gloria", "v.d.", "Bilt" as three separate items, inclusive correct punctuation.

Alas, the last name gives problems with the punctuation:

1. "G" without the dot!
2. **". v.d.**" too many dots
3. "Bilt"

So as a nice puzzle: what should be the regex?

Comment: What is the expected result for `G. v.d. Bilt`? See [`^(\w+\.?)\s*(.*?)\s*\b(\w+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/9RVYUL/1).

Comment: In case things get too simple, I recon there's also the possibility that someone is called `H.S. v.d. Bilt` or `H.-D. v.d. Bilt` ;) ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could go for

```
^                  # match beginning of the line/string
(?P<first>[\w-.]+) # match a word character (a-z_), a dash and dot
\h*                # horizontal whitespaces, zero or more
(?P<middle>.+)     # at least one character (can be a whitespace)
\h*                # horizontal whitespaces, zero or more
\b(?P<last>\w+)    # a word boundary, followed by word characters
$                  # the end of the line / string
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/ck9cLh/2).

Comment: Wow, you even thought about the dash. It correctly splits "Willem-Alexander der Nederlanden" (look up who he is).

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse: Glad to help. He's the Dutch king, isn't he?

Comment: Note for those using System.Text.RegularExpressions.Text: `\h` is not recognized. Instead use `\s` to match any whitespace. Furthemore a named group can't have a format like P<first>. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx